# Choosing how to save information from a DataGrid object

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am trying to get the data from a `DataGrid` that has 2 columns and add it to a `Dictionary`. It would be an easy task except for the fact that I then have to then save this `Dictionary` as a JSON. I am using the Newtonsoft JSON package to do this. It is critical that it is kept in the `Dictionary` for other uses within the project. I have tried two things with no success.

- Using a `Tuple` -> Didn't save to JSON, later learned that Newtonsoft doesn't support tuples.
- Using a custom class -> created a super basic class that just contained the get and set methods for two variables, also didn't save to JSON.

For more context, the two variables are a `bool` and a custom `Enum` off a `ComboBox` in the `DataGrid`.

Any suggestions on how to group these pieces of data in a JSON savable way are much appreciated.

Comment: From your question I didn't understand, why don't you just use `Dictionary` itself. Here is an example on `Dictionary` serialization: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeDictionary.htm

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear, I need to save two prices of data under the value of the dictionary.

Comment: Could you please provide the code of your custom class, that didn't get saved?